# Is it possible to create and schedule a background task in Java Hibernate/Spring MVC Web application?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have been assigned to work in a project which was built by another developer. It uses Hibernate/Spring MVC technology in Java with MySQL is database server.

Previously, by the time the project went live the first time, there was not much data, so the performance was fine. Now our client is expanding their business. A lot of data was imported and thousands more will soon be imported. Many features in the website require multiple database transactions based on user input. Performing a lot of database operations each time they navigate between pages is nightmarish to them.

I'm thinking of declaring some static variables, then creating scheduled tasks to automatically load data into the variables so they can be used globally. I know how to do this with a desktop application but I don't know if it is possible in a MVC web application. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

**UPDATED**: Another thing I forgot to mention is new data will be imported by our client's side everyday. I've made some analysis and see performance improvement can hardly be achieved via cache. The only solution I can think of is through background tasks but I'm not sure how can I achieve this.

Comment: you cam implement second level cache and connection pool so that it will improve your performance

Comment: I already did but nothing improved at all.

Comment: You can use a Scheduled task to do that or a timer (Better use application events), but i think your problem is other, on your test, performance degration happens after add data only?. Maybe you can load your entities more efficiently and your problem is your application is doing a lot of database calls, chattiness. Another thing you can do is beging using concurrent request to increase throughput on client side.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/, http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Comment: What you describe is essentially caching (in the application memory), so why do you say it won't help and still want to do it? Also please be aware that if you load a lot of data into your app memory you will likely start suffering from excessive Full GC pauses (up to total application freeze).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking for something like in .NET. I know how to implement multi-thread programming in .NET but don't know how to do the same thing in Java.